# adb install: downloaded apkm file from ApkMirror.com doesn't end with .apk

Tags: adb, installation, apk

I'm attempting to install, via `adb`, [Chrome Beta 104.0.5112.55 downloaded from APKMirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/chrome-beta/chrome-beta-104-0-5112-55-release/chrome-beta-104-0-5112-55-8-android-apk-download/).

The filename is `com.chrome.beta_104.0.5112.55-511205534_5lang_7feat_fdd8ce962abf141ecf575852ba260e4f_apkmirror.com`.

However, when I run

```
adb install -r com.chrome.beta_..._apkmirror.com
```

it complains,

> adb: usage: filename doesn't end .apk: com.chrome.beta_..._apkmirror.com

I tried changing the filename by appending an `.apk` but got

> adb: failed to install com.chrome.beta_..._apkmirror.com.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed to parse /data/app/vmdl1212970952.tmp/base.apk: AndroidManifest.xml]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most Android apps are today no longer shipped as a monolithic APK file that can be installed on every flavor of an Android device.

Instead Android apps are shipped as bunch of APK files the app is split into. The file you have downloaded from apkmirror contains such a bunch of APK file. For your convenience they are ZIPed into one file so you don't have to download half a dozen APK files.

For installing such an APK zip bundle (some times called app-bundle) you first need to unzip the downloaded file and then install the APK files using the adb command `install-multiple` and then list all the APK files you have extracted.

```
adb install-multiple base.apk filex.apk filey.apk ....
```

On Windows you have to manually provide all the file names.

On Linux/MacOS (assuming all extracted APK files are located in one directory) you can just use

```
adb install-multiple *.apk
```

and leave the resolving of the wildcard to your shell (e.g. bash).

Comment: `adb install-multiple (get-item *.apk)` for Powershell on Windows, no need to provide all the names by hand

Comment: @Soumya Usually in those apkm or apks files you download fro apkmirror there are all languages and all CPU-architectures present. Installing al of them will just waste space on your phone without any advantage fro you.

Comment: I was merely pointing out that "On Windows you have to manually provide all the file names." is not necessary, and a mechanism similar to linux/macos "*.apk" exists. Of course if you need to select a subset of the apks, then you need to pass the list by hand on all platforms.