# Converting APKM to APK so that I can install it manually by a default installer

Tags: apk

As written in the title, I just downloaded an official app from APK Mirror, it has 2 files apk and apkm and since the apk version didn't work, I tried to download the second one i.e. the apkm one. I don't know how to install it.

[image]

So I googled and found [this](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/io.github.muntashirakon.unapkm/). Yes, I'm aware of the article that says converting APKM to APKS, it doesn't matter because I have a tool to convert APKS to APK

I don't know if it's a scam or not  but the app that's called unapkm, after installing it, it doesn't have the "open" option and the app isn't appeared on the screen or perhaps I just don't know how to use it. Anyway, is there any chance to convert the apkm to apk so I can install it normally from my phone?

[image]

Comment: This is also discussed on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/fv1haf/what_is_apkm_format/)

Comment: Thank you. The thing is reddit is banned in my country, so your link, (I'm sorry) I couldn't open it. Could you tell me the main discussion plz? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Creating universal APK form multiple APKs without having *.aab (Android App Bundle) file](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231304/44325)

Comment: @user516076 You can always read Reddit pages via Teddit, try e.g. this one: https://teddit.pussthecat.org/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/fv1haf/what_is_apkm_format/ (there are more Teddit instances if needed). Further, with UnApkm installed, have you tried to "start" the APKM file? Maybe the app has registered for that, like the installer reacts on APKs (and neither has an "open" option).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [adb install: filename doesn't end .apk](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247728/adb-install-filename-doesnt-end-apk)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I have read them all. The adb thing looks difficult to do, so I probably try it later. And one of your link from the reddit suggest using the exact same app like the link I provide i.e. unapkm, i've tried it but it doesn't work. I even tried to install the apkmirror installer from google play but it failed. It says **The bundle requires Android SDK 31 but you have Android 11**. What happened?

Comment: When I tried SAI installer, it said **failed to allocate 68309932 because only 0 allocatable**. What does that mean?

Comment: I think I have found the problem. I can't install the apk or the apkm because there's something wrong with the Androidmanifest.xml. I tried to analyze the app and compare it with the previous version, and when I replaced the file, it was able to be installed. If that's the case, what's the problem and what should I do to fix the Androidmanifest? Is there any related problem like this? Thanks

Comment: To the OP, I'm sorry about that, I saved the reddit as a pdf and uploaded it to a file host - https://easyupload.io/rkvl0t I don't like to regurgitate other people's comments as my own. To the moderator I posted another answer because I cannot comment.